# Can QEMU switch between KVM and TCG dynamically?

Tags: qemu, kvm

I have a follow-up question regarding the internals of QEMU. After familiarizing with large segments of the software, I wonder, whether it is possible to switch between KVM (accelerated) and TCQ (emulated) execution during run time.

It appears that no arbitrary switch point can be chosen since the KVM won't report the state of every register (machine state) at each individual step of execution. Therefore there must be a natural barrier.

From my observations, method-calls and return instruction can serve as this, since they will have to deal with the state of the execution. (Creating the stack for the callee and restoring the stack for the caller after the callee finished its execution.)

My plan is to control the switching, based on instruction-profiling in a way, such that the execution is transferred to the KVM as soon as particular instruction sequences are not found.

Any kind of hints on that topic would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking whether it's currently possible (it isn't) or whether it might in theory be possible to change QEMU to make it possible (maybe but I suspect a very large amount of work) ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually both. But after looking into the code (and how it works: with callgrind) I also found out, that there is currently no direct support for this. I'm even not sure whether the qemu-user-mode supports KVM. The goal I am trying to achieve is a primary emulated run, and as soon segments (large enough to justify the overhead) are executed (and analyzed) once, they can be executed on the hardware (by KVM) natively. (In theory.)

Comment: user-mode never supports KVM. If you want to run a binary that's the same architecture as the host, you can just run it directly without having QEMU there at all. user-mode is only interesting for cross-architecture emulation.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. That I could run it directly on the architecture appears to me, but I was wondering if it is possible to run a "bare-metal" application on x86 via kvm. But then - from my findings - the binary would be passed through via KVM such that the execution is beyond Qemus control. Unfortunately the Idea does not turn out as planned. Probably I can archive a "supervised" execution by using Linux perf.